# Convert following class properties into Json format

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I need to convert following **Employee.cs** class in json format,for that i wrote following code
//Employee.cs(In class file)

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Job { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

//In my MyPage.aspx page

```
Employee oEmployee1 =
       new Employee { Name = "Pini", Job = "111", City = "30" };

        Employee oEmployee2 =
              new Employee { Name = "Yaniv", Job = "Developer", City = "Hyd" };
        Employee oEmployee3 =
                new Employee { Name = "Yoni", Job = "Developer", City = "Bglre" };

        List<Employee> oList = new List<Employee>() { oEmployee1, oEmployee2, oEmployee3 };
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer =new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(oList);
Response.Write("<pre>"+sJSON+"</pre>");
```

I got following output:

```
[{"Name":"Pini","Job":"111","City":"30"},{"Name":"Yaniv","Job":"Developer","City":"Hyd"},{"Name":"Yoni","Job":"Developer","City":"Bglre"}]
```

Is it any other way to convert to json format more effectively and i want to beautify json output

Answer (score 3):

I would use [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) Serializer with `Formatting.Indented` like below

```
string result= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented);
```

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Pini",
    "Job": "111",
    "City": "30"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Yaniv",
    "Job": "Developer",
    "City": "Hyd"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Yoni",
    "Job": "Developer",
    "City": "Bglre"
  }
]
```

Comment: can you send that code in detail.How to add NuGet Package JSON.NET package.How to included in namespace.........can u tel in detail

Answer (score 0):

```
list<Employee> oEmployee=
{
new Employee() { Name = "Pini", Job = "111", City = "30" },
new Employee() { Name = "Pini", Job = "111", City = "30" },
new Employee() { Name = "Pini", Job = "111", City = "30" },

};

var oSerializer=new JavaScriptSerializer();
string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(oList);
Response.Write("<pre>"+sJSON+"</pre>");
```

add the   **System.Web.Script.Serialization** reference

add refer this link

http://matijabozicevic.com/blog/csharp-net-development/csharp-serialize-object-to-json-format-using-javascriptserialization